# .NET 6 System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform With Fitnesse

Tags: .net-6.0, fitsharp

When creating a new .net 6 project with Microsoft.Data.SqlClient It works fine. But When running through a .net 6 fitnesse project with fitsharp we are getting this error:

System.PlatformNotSupportedException: Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform

Dependancies:

1. Fitsharp 2022.1.15
2. Lextm.SharpSnmpLib 12.4.0
3. Microsoft.Data.SqlClient 4.1.0

I've tried adding `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` to .csproj

That bypassed some errors, But the `PlatformNotSupportedExcpetion` is still present.

When converting to a console app and running from program. It works fine. But it won't work when running through fitnesse with fitsharp

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The work around for now was to downgrade `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient` to `2.0.1`. And install the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.Runtime v2.0.1` nuget package. Having `<CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>true</CopyLocalLockFileAssemblies>` was needed, but this didn't copy the Microsoft.Data dll's to bin on build. So These two dll's needed to be move to bin:

1. `packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient.sni.runtime\2.0.1\runtimes\win-x64\native\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.dll`
2. `packages\microsoft.data.sqlclient\2.0.1\runtimes\win\lib\netcoreapp3.1\Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.dll`

A Similar solution was found here for .NET Core 3.1:

[Issues for Fitsharp in Github](https://github.com/jediwhale/fitsharp/issues/169)

Naun, answered it on 13th July, but the difference for .NET 6 was to also install the `Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SNI.Runtime v2.0.1` nuget package and copy different versions of the dll's

Comment: And what if I am building for Any CPU ?