# Exception when using Microsoft.Data.Sqlclient Ado.net with project .Net core 6.0 project library

Tags: c#, .net-6.0, microsoft-data-sqlclient

I have an exception when I use sql.data.client to query database sqlserver :

> system.platformnotsupportedexception microsoft.data.sqlclient is not supported on this platform

My code source :

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        using (var cmd = new SqlCommand(queryString, connection))
        {
              cmd.Connection = connection;
              connection.Open();

              using (SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader())
              {
                   while (reader.Read())
                   {
                       return true;
                   }                               
              }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Go to project properties and set the target os to windows, and if it is a cross platform application then you need to use the correct nuget package

Comment: And in project properties also verify that your target framework is .Net 6

Comment: Its a versioning issue with your Nuget Package, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71022502/495455 and here https://github.com/dotnet/SqlClient/issues/289 and please include your research next time and what you've tried so we don't recommend things you've already tried. In this case a screenshot would be helpful.

Comment: @MuhammadWaqasAziz Thank you for your response py target Framework is .NET 6

Comment: @JeremyThompson  I followed the steps and i have other exeption : System.TypeInitializationException : 'The type initializer for 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection' threw an exception.'  and FileNotFoundException : Could not load file or assembly 'System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter, Version=0.0.0.0,

Comment: Google it and try all the solutions and if none work, come back and ask a new question. https://www.google.com/search?q=%22Could+not+load+file+or+assembly+%27System.Diagnostics.PerformanceCounter%22 Your machine doesn't look like its in good shape, if you continue to get issues one after the other consider rebuilding your PC and starting off on the right foot. I'm not sure how you're getting these exceptions...

Comment: [later dup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72559921/system-data-sqlclient-is-not-supported-on-this-platform-in-net-6-0-c-sharp-libr)

Answer (score 0):

**Is not supported on this platform** error typically means you tried to load an x64 assembly in a x86 process or vice versa.

Microsoft.Data.SqlClient contains architecture specific files.

Double check your Nuget Package is for the correct architecture your machine supports.

Comment: I use Any CPU so I think it did work for x86 and x64

Comment: I have this exeption System.PlatformNotSupportedException : 'Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not supported on this platform.'

Comment: If I have an class library calls `new SqlConnection()` and If I use this class library in a .exe file then I also get the same exception. Both class library and the c# console application is build using `any CPU`

Comment: @hbib how you managed to solve this problem?

Comment: I have changed the nuget from Microsoft.Data.SqlClient to system.data.sqlclient